# pip calculator unexpected ending e.d

Tags: compiler-errors, mql4, metatrader4

I've been working on an Expert advisor course for Metatrader 4 and I keep getting errors with my code and I don't see the mistake.

I seem to have closed everything, and I don't see the mistake, anyone who can help?

the goal of the code is to know what a pip is, and to calculate the Take profit and the stoploss depending on the entryprice and a stuck pip value

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                               CalculateStoplossAndTakeProfit.mqh |
//|                                                Jiano van Goethem |
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Jiano van Goethem"
#property link      ""
#property strict

#include <Pipcalculator.mqh>
void OnStart()
{
//---

Alert("");
double SignalPrice = 1.368;
int TakeProfitPips = 50;
int StoplossPips = 50;
double GetPipValue = GetPip

   if(Ask < SignalPrice) // buying
   {
      Alert("sending buy order ");
      double StopLossPrice = Ask - StoplossPips * GetPipValue();
      double TakeProfitPrice = Ask + TakeProfitPips * GetPipValue();
      Alert("entry price = " + Ask);
      Alert ("Stop loss price = " +   StopLossPrice);
      Alert ("Take profit price = " + TakeProfitPrice);
      
   //send buyorder
   }
   else if(Bid > SignalPrice) // selling
   {
      Alert("sending sell order ");
      double StopLossPrice = Bid + StoplossPips * GetPipValue();
      double TakeProfitPrice = Bid - TakeProfitPips * GetPipValue();
      Alert("entry price = " + Bid);
      Alert ("Stop loss price = " + StopLossPrice);
      Alert ("Take profit price = " + int(TakeProfitPrice));
   //send sellorder
   }
  }
```

> Unexpected end of program line 51

```
//Function to calculate the decimal digits
//Digits is a native variable in MetaTrader which is assigned as a value the number of digits after the point
   double PipValue = GetPipValueFromDigits()
   double GetPipValueFromDigits()
   {   //If there are 3 or less digits (JPY for example) then return 0.01 which is the pip value
   if(Digits<=3){
      return(0.01);
   }
   //If there are 4 or more digits then return 0.0001 which is the pip value
   else if(Digits>=4){
      return(0.0001);
   }
   //In all other cases (there shouldn't be any) return 0
   else return(0);{
   }
}
```

> unbalanced parenthesis line 11

Comment: you are missing a close bracket for your function at the end of the file.

Comment: Is the second code snippet from Pipcalculator.mqh? You have unnecessary opening and closing curled brackets near the end (after `else return(0);`). Also, your first code snippet is missing a semicolon at the end of this line: `double GetPipValue = GetPip`. Besides, GetPip looks to be undefined.